# Netplan Bridge Does Not Support Multiple Interfaces

Tags: networking, netplan, network-bridge, virtualbox-networking, nic

### Issue:

When bridging multiple NICs using netplan, client hosts connected to the
bridged NICs cannot communicate with the gateway server.  The goal is to have all
bridged NICs share the same static IP address on the gateway.  How do I configure
netplan to properly bridge two or more NICs?

### Motivation:

I am trying to mock-up a virtual network with gateway to imitate a physical
topology.  This will allow me to test changes on the virtual network before
deploying to the live environment.

I am using Virtual Box, Ubuntu 22.04 guest VMs on an Ubuntu 22.04 host for this
purpose.  I created a gateway VM and four client VMs for testing.  I have
created a VBox bridged (gateway) NIC to my physical LAN.  I have also created
four VBox internal network NICs on the virtual gateway.  There is a client VM
for each VBox internal network connected to each VBox internal network.  Three
of the four clients should share the same (static) IP address via the bridge on
the gateway.  I do not want to use VBox DHCP nor DNS as I am trying to simulate
a physical topology.

### Troubleshooting:

I believe I have narrowed the problem to the bridge portion of my (virtual)
topology.

- I can access a client that is not on the bridge from the gateway. In
  fact, if I configure netplan without a bridge, I can access all clients on their
  respective NICs.  However, if I bridge any NIC, there is no response from the
  remote host.
- There is a Kea DHCP service and bind9 DNS service running on the gateway. The
  client VMs all get assigned addresses correctly. I can verify this by running
  `ip a` on the clients. I can also do `nslookup` on the gateway to verify the
  client IP addresses. I can do `nslookup` for the gateway VM on any of the
  clients that are not in a bridge. Clients via the bridge cannot do `nslookup` on
  the gateway VM.
- I used `tcpdump` to capture ICMP packets on both the virtual
  gateway and on the client VMs. The captures show requests leaving the gateway
  through both the bridge and NICs. Then I see the clients receiving requests and
  sending replies. However, the bridge and the gateway NICs never show the replies.
- Setting yaml `macaddress` parameter on bridge to the MAC address of any of the
  bridge `interfaces` allows traffic to return to that gateway.
- Setting `MACAddressPolicy=none` in */usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link*
  assigns MAC address of last NIC in `interfaces` list from yaml allows traffic to return to that
  gateway.

### VM Topology:

| Interface | Bridge | IP Address | Subnet CIDR | Attached Host | Example DNS addr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| enp0s3 | - | (from external LAN) | 192.168.1.0/24 | vgate * | 192.168.1.34/24 |
| enp0s8 | - | 192.168.100.1 | 192.168.100.0/25 | client3 + | 192.168.100.16/25 |
| br0 | - | 192.168.100.129 | 192.168.100.128/26 | - | - |
| enp0s9 | br0 | (from VM gateway) | "" | client4 + | 192.168.100.130/26 |
| enp0s10 | br0 | (from VM gateway) | "" | client5 + | 192.168.100.131/26 |
| enp0s16 | br0 | (from VM gateway) | "" | client6 + | 192.168.100.132/26 |

** VM gateway*
*+ VM client*

```
                                          gateway
                            +---------------------------------+         client 3
                            |                                 |       +----------+
      nnnnnnnnnn            |                        enpos8  [ ]<--->[ ] enp0s3  |
  nnnn          nnnn        |            (192.168.100.1/25)   |       |  (dhcp)  |
 (                  )       |                                 |       +----------+
(  external network  )<--->[ ] enp0s3  I                      |
(  (192.168.1.0/24)  )      |  (dhcp)                         |         client 4
 (                  )       |                                 |       +----------+
  uuuu          uuuu        |                      { enpos9  [ ]<--->[ ] enp0s3  |
      uuuuuuuuuu            |                      {          |       |  (dhcp)  |
                            |                      {          |       +----------+
                            |                      {          |
                            |                      {          |         client 5
                            |                      {          |       +----------+
                            |                  br0 { enpos10 [ ]<--->[ ] enp0s3  |
                            | (192.168.100.129/26) {          |       |  (dhcp)  |
                            |                      {          |       +----------+
                            |                      {          |
                            |                      {          |         client 6
                            |                      {          |       +----------+
                            |                      { enpos16 [ ]<--->[ ] enp0s3  |
                            |                                 |       |  (dhcp)  |
                            |                                 |       +----------+
                            +---------------------------------+
```

### Netplans:

Installed with `netplan apply`.

#### Gateway netplan

```
$> cat /etc/netplan/00-gateway.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      nameservers:
        search: [home.mylab.org]
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.100.1/25]
      nameservers:
        search: [home.mylabtest.org]
        addresses: [192.168.100.1]
    bridge4:
      match:
        name: enp0s9
    bridge5:
      match:
        name: enp0s10
    bridge6:
      match:
        name: enp0s16
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [bridge4,bridge5,bridge6]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.100.129/26]
      nameservers:
        search: [home.mylabtest.org]
        addresses: [192.168.100.1]
      parameters:
         stp: false
         forward-delay: 30
```

#### Clients netplan

```
$> cat /etc/netplan/00-lan.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      nameservers:
        search: [home.mylabtest.org]
        addresses: [192.168.100.1]
```

#### Gateway Routes

```
$> ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.34 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.34 metric 100
192.168.1.1 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.34 metric 100
192.168.100.0/25 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1
192.168.100.128/26 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.129
```

#### Gateway netfilter

```
$> nft list ruleset
table ip mangle {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        iifname "enp0s3" ip daddr 192.168.100.0/24 ct state established,related counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        oifname "enp0s3" ip saddr 192.168.100.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain LOGGING {
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type nat hook input priority 100; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname "enp0s3" counter packets 189 bytes 15392 masquerade
    }
}
```

#### Gateway Interfaces

```
$> ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:04:42:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.34/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 554868sec preferred_lft 554868sec
    inet6 fdca:ccc:607e:1c4b:a00:27ff:fe04:4201/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 1264sec preferred_lft 1264sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe04:4201/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:9a:59:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/25 brd 192.168.100.127 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9a:597b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp0s9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:52:5a:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp0s10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:54:3c:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp0s16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:75:83:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:13:a8:43:d8:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.129/26 brd 192.168.100.191 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d813:a8ff:fe43:d834/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### Client Interfaces

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:47:8f:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.120/26 metric 100 brd 192.168.100.127 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 3321sec preferred_lft 3321sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe47:8fc7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### tcpdump on VM gateway:

```
$> ping -c3 client4
PING client4.home.mylabtest.org (192.168.100.130) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- client4.home.mylabtest.org ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2025ms

$> tcpdump -i br0 -n icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
02:36:58.005888 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 1, length 64
02:36:59.008749 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 2, length 64
02:37:00.031348 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 3, length 64

$> tcpdump -i enp0s9 -n icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s9, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
02:36:58.005899 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 1, length 64
02:36:59.008773 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 2, length 64
02:37:00.031361 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 3, length 64
```

#### tcpdump on client VM:

```
$> tcpdump -i enp0s3 -n icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
02:36:58.003563 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 1, length 64
02:36:58.003606 IP 192.168.100.130 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 4, seq 1, length 64
02:36:59.006400 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 2, length 64
02:36:59.006436 IP 192.168.100.130 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 4, seq 2, length 64
02:37:00.029006 IP 192.168.100.129 > 192.168.100.130: ICMP echo request, id 4, seq 3, length 64
02:37:00.029050 IP 192.168.100.130 > 192.168.100.129: ICMP echo reply, id 4, seq 3, length 64
```

#### network reports on VM gateway:

```
$> networkctl show
IDX LINK    TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo      loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 enp0s3  ether    routable    configured
  3 enp0s8  ether    routable    configured
  4 enp0s9  ether    enslaved    configured
  5 enp0s10 ether    enslaved    configured
  6 enp0s16 ether    enslaved    configured
  7 br0     bridge   routable    configured

7 links listed.
```

```
$> brctl show
bridge name    bridge id            STP enabled    interfaces
br0            8000.da13a843d834    no             enp0s10
                                                   enp0s16
                                                   enp0s9
```

```
$> netplan status
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: none
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: none
WARNING:root:Unknown device type: none
     Online state: online
    DNS Addresses: 127.0.0.53 (stub)
       DNS Search: home.lab.org
                   home.labtest.org

●  1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)
      MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00
        Addresses: 127.0.0.1/8
                   ::1/128
           Routes: ::1 metric 256

●  2: enp0s3 ethernet UP (networkd: enp0s3)
      MAC Address: 08:00:27:89:13:55 (Intel Corporation)
        Addresses: 192.168.13.117/24 (dhcp)
                   fdca:ccc:607e:1c4b:a00:27ff:fe89:1355/64
                   fe80::a00:27ff:fe89:1355/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.13.1
       DNS Search: home.lab.org
           Routes: default via 192.168.13.1 from 192.168.13.117 metric 100 (dhcp)
                   192.168.13.0/24 from 192.168.13.117 metric 100 (link)
                   192.168.13.1 from 192.168.13.117 metric 100 (dhcp, link)
                   fdca:ccc:607e:1c4b::/64 metric 100 (ra)
                   fde7:2a4f:880b::/64 via fe80::185a:c799:e3d0:29f7 metric 100 (ra)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256

●  3: enp0s8 ethernet UP (networkd: enp0s8)
      MAC Address: 08:00:27:53:59:8f (Intel Corporation)
        Addresses: 192.168.100.1/25
                   fe80::a00:27ff:fe53:598f/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.100.1
       DNS Search: home.labtest.org
           Routes: 192.168.100.0/25 from 192.168.100.1 (link)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256

●  4: enp0s9 ethernet UP (networkd: bridge4)
      MAC Address: 08:00:27:f0:70:e5 (Intel Corporation)

●  5: enp0s10 ethernet UP (networkd: bridge5)
      MAC Address: 08:00:27:90:f6:99 (Intel Corporation)

●  6: enp0s16 ethernet UP (networkd: bridge6)
      MAC Address: 08:00:27:ae:41:4b (Intel Corporation)

●  7: br0 bridge UP (networkd: br0)
      MAC Address: 42:dc:f8:69:8d:ad
        Addresses: 192.168.100.129/26
                   fe80::40dc:f8ff:fe69:8dad/64 (link)
    DNS Addresses: 192.168.100.1
       DNS Search: home.labtest.org
           Routes: 192.168.100.128/26 from 192.168.100.129 (link)
                   fe80::/64 metric 256
```

### Links:

[Netplan Yaml Bridges](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-device-type-bridges)
[Netplan How To](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-configure-network-bridges)
[Netplan Examples](https://netplan.io/examples)
[Ubuntu Manpages: systemd-networkd](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/systemd.network.5.html)
[Ubuntu Manpages: netplan](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/netplan.5.html)
[Netplan Bug 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/2051441)
[Netplan Bug 2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1860781)

Comment: Is Ask Ubuntu the right resource for this question? Would you more likely get better responses directing it to [this site](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: You're probably right.  This may not be a Netplan problem as I get similar results using ifupdown.  I was not aware of that site.  Thanks for the suggestion.